# How to terminate error message

Tags: php

I have part of script, which sometimes may return warning or error, but it still works and I want to terminate all error messages from this part of script. Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

```
function ping($host, $port, $timeout) {
    $tB = microtime(true);
    $fP = fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!isset($fP)) return 'down';
    $tA = microtime(true);
    return round((($tA - $tB) * 1000), 0)." ms";
}

echo ping('www.blahblahblah.com', 80, 10);
```

problem is that when it fails (target doesnt exists), it returns error message and 'down'(intended response), so I want to terminate those error reports.

---

EDIT:
To be clear, when it fails, it outputs system error message + my intended error message, so I wanted to have only my message and dont show system message.

Comment: Error messages can be stored in many different ways... you must show us the code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Why not just check if it exists before trying to ping it. It is Always better to fix errors and warnings rather than hide them. If you are getting errors, it is normally because you are doing something you shouldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try: `error_reporting(0);`

http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php

or `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can mute warnings, notices, errors etc. by using [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function or using `@` sign (eg. `@somefunction()`). But remember - ignoring errors is probably not a good idea.

You can also make own error handler by using [`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for us to know how to delete error warnings from your site if you can't even tell us how they're stored.

If It's stored in a session and you know the session name, then you could do something like (unsetting the variable).

```
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
```

But then again, it's hard for us to tell without code :)